# How and why do sunspots occur?

Tags: magnetic-fields, astrophysics, sun

I am studying [sunspot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunspot) behavior, and the causes for the occurrence sunspots occur. I've come across the phrase 'local magnetic fields of the Sun'. I have no idea what that means. 
Can someone please explain to me how/why sunspots form?

Comment: Can you give some context for the phrase?

Comment: Here is the exact sentence: 'However, superimposed on this basic field (called a dipole field) is a much more complex series of local fields that vary over time. Places where the Sun's magnetic field is especially strong are called active regions, and often produce telltale sunspots.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sun is a giant turbulent ball of plasma. It has a certain amount of angular momentum that gives rise to currents, and magnetic fields. As the large planets (Jupiter and Uranus) orbit the Sun, they cause the Sun to wobble about the barycenter. This disturbs the magnetic fields and creates local "vortices" that cause magnetic field lines to move in and out of the sun's surface:

[image]

Image and inspiration for this answer from [this link](http://www.uvs-model.com/WFE%20on%20sunspot.htm) which I recommend for further reading.

Because plasmas are "confined" by magnetic field lines, the temperature of the surface of the sun as observed from Earth is changed by the presence of these magnetic fields and the associated coronal flares that follow these lines. An explanation for how that creates a sun spot is given by this image [(found on this page)](http://www.physast.uga.edu/~rls/astro1020/ch15/ovhd.html) :

[image]

[image source](http://www.physast.uga.edu/~rls/1020/ch15/15-17a.jpg)

Comment: I do appreciate your answer, but to tell the truth I'm kind of a beginner to astrophysics, so I can't understand some of the specialist terms. Sorry !

Comment: OK. "Convection" - currents in the sun that cause the hot plasma from inside to come to the surface. A plasma is like a gas, except that it's so hot that the electrons don't stay attached to the atoms. This means it's a "soup" of positively or negatively charged particles, and charged particles are bent by a magnetic field. Because of this, they can only travel in a spiral patch around the field lines - we say they are "trapped" by the field. That disturbs the usual churning - and means that as the surface cools, it is not replaced with fresh hot plasma. Cooler = darker. Better?

Comment: so does that mean that the hot gaseous ions can't escape (via convection) onto the top of the photosphere? .. and thats why they're cooler ?

Comment: They don't get replaced by fresh hot ions and that's why they're cooler.

Comment: I think I get it now. But can you please explain why charged particles are bent by a magnetic field? also what do you mean by the fact that  they can only travel in a spiral patch around the field lines ? Many thanks!

Comment: Sorry typo meant "path" not "patch". See for example http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/atmos/aurora.html - a charges particle will feel a force from the magnetic field that is perpendicular to its velocity and perpendicular to the magnetic field. This naturally results in the particle "wrapping itself" around the magnetic field lines. This is the same mechanism that protects Earth from most solar wind and causes Aurora Borealis.